# Allow more pages with facebook graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-php-sdk

My app successfully connects to Facebook using Facebook's Graph API, requests access to the pages I want to post to and redirects back to my app. That works like charm.

My problem is that if I created a new page on Facebook, I cannot add it to my app:
When I try to connect again, Facebook seems to know what I have requested earlier and I'm immediately redirected to my app without the request which pages I want to allow access to.

How to reconnect or what's the normal way to fix that problem?

I use Facebook's PHP Graph SDK 5.7.

Comment: Go to https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications, remove the permission, and then login to the app again.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe - that was my idea also, but the app is not shown!?! I don't know why - perhaps because it's not validated by Facebook?

Comment: That should not matter; after all, you are able to access & use the app. Try Graph API Explorer, pick your app from the dropdown, and then try to `X` the permission from the list. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Answer (score 0):

@CBroe That didn't work either, but then I've cleared all permissions and chosen to reopen the site selector dialog, chosen all sites and closed, removed the information from my database and reconnected... Now the dialog appeared! Thank you for your help! Helped me a lot!